# Doesn't a beamsplitter contradict the nocloning theorem?

Tags: continuous-variable

I am new to continuous variable quantum computing. From my understanding, in homodyne detection, the state (usually coherent) is duplicated and two measurements with different photon counting operators are used, the difference of which is equal to a quadrature. But isn't this a contradiction with the noclone theorem ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: are you referring to the fact that a coherent state $|\alpha\rangle$ passing through a balanced beamsplitter results in two coherent states of the form $|\alpha/\sqrt2\rangle$? If so, no there is no problem. No-cloning refers to the fact that you cannot have a unitary evolution sending $|\psi\rangle$ to $|\psi\rangle|\psi\rangle$ *for all $|\psi\rangle$*. A beamsplitter will kind of "clone" coherent states, sure, but it won't behave the same on other types of states. See eg what happens for a $n$-photon states

Comment: @glS I have added my reference, They do not give us the resulting states form, only the new operators, But if we can clone coherent states doesn't that defeat the whole security of QKD which is the purpose of the GG02 protocol and others (using coherent states) ?

Comment: don't know enough about the QKD protocol you're referring to to comment on that. But note that even for coherent states is not actually "real" cloning. There's no unitary sending $|\alpha\rangle$ to $|\alpha/\sqrt2\rangle$ for all $\alpha$. The state $|\alpha/\sqrt2\rangle^{\otimes 2}$ might look similar to two copies of $|\alpha\rangle$ but $|\alpha/\sqrt2\rangle$ has a different average number of bosons and is just in general different from $|\alpha\rangle$. I don't see in that reference where the authors say that the coherent states are "duplicated" by the BS

Comment: @glS  The GG02 protocol is basically the most common CV protocol for QKD. Alice encodes a complex number p+iq as the coherent $|p+iq\rangle$. Bob can then estimate one of them, because the expectation of the $\hat{p}$ operator for example is p. Since $\hat{p}$ and $\hat{q}$ are unphysical, we use homodyne detection to emulate them using photon counting. At least that's my understanding. The authors do not say the coherent states are duplicated, but that's the only way I see that make sense for D7 and D8 (all operators should be evaluated at the same argument)